# Arduino Uno with data logging shield has a problem switching power sources

Tags: arduino-uno, power

I have the basic Adafruit "Light & Temperature data logger Tutorial kit" made, and it works well when connected to a PC, but when I unplug the PC USB connection and hook it up to another power source, it will not launch and run by itself. I have reset both the logger and Arduino board reset buttons, but it does not seem to start recording data to a new file. One of my power sources was a Solar panel / Solar Lithium Battery charger  (with the "Power Boost 500 basic 5V boost board, and an another alternate power source was a 6 x AA battery holder with a barrel jack connector. What am I missing here? I'm a newbie! Thanks.

Comment: what have you done to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: Can you measure the right voltage at your power inputs? (9V at the barrel Jack vor 5V directly tied to the 5V-pin of the arduino)

Comment: I checked and changed to new AA batteries, and obtained 9V on the battery pack jack, and checked and obtained the 5V pin on the arduino also. The serial monitor will start showing data for a while on its own. When I come back and refresh the PC, it starts up again. I noticed that it had 6 readings initially, and then continued with reading number 20, 21, etc. The SD disk file however, did not show any additional of the missing readings!  I may have a program code issue (maybe?). (To "chrism" , and "jstotola").

Comment: My troubleshooting so far leads me to the likely issue of enough alternative power, and possibly the sketch feature that has to do with the "sync_interval" time before a number of readings is written to the disk. I had not appreciated this feature, and may have pulled out the SD to see what was recorded and lost a good number of readings.....AFAIK.